# how to name dataframe columns based on classes arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Spending a huge time on this. I have a `tuple` of non-callable `classes`, all named `SymbolInfo`, with same `attribute` labels. Lets say:

```
In: print(my_tuple)
Out: (SymbolInfo(att_1=False, att_2=0, att_3=1.0),SymbolInfo(att_1=True, att_2=0, att_3=1.5))
```

My objective is to create a dataframe from this `tuple`. When I convert it to `list`, it works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_tuple))
```

I get the dataframe, but I don't get the column labels, which should be the name of the `classes` `attributes`: (i.e. `att_1`, `att_2`, `att_3`).

The attributes names and their quantity (not values) are standardized for all `classes`. So I could consider any `class` to get it.

I've tried methods like `inspect.getmembers(my_tuple[0])` and `inspect.getfullargspec(my_tuple[0]).args` without success. It's important to get those arguments in the same sequence that they appear.

Comment: are those named tuples?

Comment: Why don't you just rename those columns on the dataframe creation?

Comment: It is a tuple imported from other app. I guess is tuple of classes. When I print the type of say `my_tuple[0]` the result is `<class 'SymbolInfo'>`

Comment: I could rename it, but I would like to be dynamic with the original app. if the app changes someday I dont need to change as well.

Comment: so i would find some method to extract the class names as a list/tuple and pass it to the names/columns parameter. That way i would keep the bit that's working of that code (the values)

Comment: If you have access to class code, you can implement `__iter__` method.

Comment: I've tried something like this too. `attr=inspect.getmembers(my_typle[0])` `col_list=[a for a in attr if not(a[0].startswith('__') and a[0].endswith('__'))]`, but the arguments come in alphabetical order, not in the order that they were stated

Comment: Do you realize that order of the keyword parameters inside a function is not important right? I mean `SymbolInfo(att_1=False, att_2=0, att_3=1)` and `SymbolInfo(att_2=0, att_3=1, att_1=False)` gives two objects with exact same data.

Comment: @DanielArges Can you show the output of  `signature(my_tuple[0].__init__)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang My dataframe created comes with the data in this sequence. I need to name the columns in the same sequence.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma (*args, **kwargs)

Comment: @DanielArges if possible can you please include the expected output? And also include the output that you are getting while using `df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_tuple))`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma . Posted on question edition

Comment: @DanielArges When you call `str(my_tuple[0])`, are all the required attributes gets printed in the representation? And you have stated in the comments below that you can't access the `__dict__` of the symbol info object...then i guess these objects are using `__slots__`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Got this solution:

```
my_dict = my_tuple[0]._asdict()
my_col_list = list(my_dict.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes (in the order they were added) with the `__dict__` method, like so:

```
class thing():
    def __init__(self, att_1, att_2, att_3):
        self.z_att_1 = att_1
        self.att_2 = att_2
        self.att_3 = att_3

a = thing('bob', 'eve', 'alice')
b = thing('john', 'jack', 'dan')
c = (a,b)

# see the attributes
print(c[0].__dict__)
```

Results in.

```
# note that z_att_1 is first
{'z_att_1': 'bob', 'att_2': 'eve', 'att_3': 'alice'}
```

Now you can loop through the dictionary and pull out the keys for the attribute names.

Comment: The classes are not callable. I don't know if this explains this message: `AttributeError: 'SymbolInfo' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a dict from class and then create dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda x: x.__dict__, my_tuple)))
```

And I recommend using `attrs` library for OOP in python.